# AWS Firehose cross region/account policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to create Firehose streams that can receive data from different regions in Account A, through AWS Lambda, and output into a redshift table in Account B. To do this I created an IAM role on Account A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I gave it the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "redshift:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

On Account B I created a role with this trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:ExternalId": "11111111111"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I gave that role the following access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-account-logs",
                "arn:aws:s3:::b-account-logs/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "redshift:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:redshift:us-east-1:cluster:account-b-cluster*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I also edited the access policy on the S3 buckets to give access to my Account A role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/AccountAXAccountBPolicy"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket","arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, none of this works. When I try to create the the stream in Account A it does not list the buckets in Account B nor the redshift cluster. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "grab data from different regions"? Amazon Kinesis Firehose does not *grab* data. Rather, applications *send* data to the Firehose, and Firehose then stores that data into Amazon S3, Amazon Redshift or the Amazon Elasticsearch Service.

Comment: Sorry, I can clarify that. The idea is that I will have lambda functions sending data to the firehose streams. Though it seems I would have 1 stream, and several lambda functions across regional endpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John's answer is semi correct. I would recommend that the account owner of the Redshift Cluster creates the FireHose Stream. Creating through CLI requires you to supply the user name and password. Having the cluster owner create the stream and sharing IAM Role permissions on the stream is safer for security and in case of credential change. Additionally, you cannot create a stream that accesses a database outside of the region, so have the delivery application access the correct stream and region.

Read on to below to see how to create the cross account stream.

In my case both accounts are accessible to me and to lower the amount of changes and ease of monitoring I created the stream on Account A side.

The above permissions are right however, you cannot create a Firehose Stream from Account A to Account B through AWS Console. You need to do it through AWS Cli:

```
 aws firehose create-delivery-stream --delivery-stream-name testFirehoseStreamToRedshift 
 --redshift-destination-configuration 'RoleARN="arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/AccountAXAccountBRole", ClusterJDBCURL="jdbc:redshift://<cluster-url>:<cluster-port>/<>",
 CopyCommand={DataTableName="<schema_name>.x_test",DataTableColumns="ID1,STRING_DATA1",CopyOptions="csv"},Username="<Cluster_User_name>",Password="<Cluster_Password>",S3Configuration={RoleARN="arn:aws:iam::11111111111:role/AccountAXAccountBRole",
 BucketARN="arn:aws:s3:::b-bucket",Prefix="test/",CompressionFormat="UNCOMPRESSED"}'
```

You can test this by creating a test table on the other AWS Account:

```
create table test_schema.x_test
(
    ID1 INT8 NOT NULL,
    STRING_DATA1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
)
distkey(ID1)
sortkey(ID1,STRING_DATA1);
```

You can send test data like this:

```
aws firehose put-record  --delivery-stream-name testFirehoseStreamToRedshift --record '{"DATA":"1,\"ABCDEFGHIJ\""}'
```

This with the permissions configuration above should create the cross account access for you.

Documentation:
Create Stream - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/create-delivery-stream.html

Put Record - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/firehose/put-record.html

Answer (score 1):

No.

Amazon Kinesis Firehose will only output to Amazon S3 buckets and Amazon Redshift clusters in the same region.

However, **anything can send information to Kinesis Firehose** by simply calling the appropriate endpoint. So, you could have applications in any AWS Account and in any Region (or anywhere on the Internet) send data to the Firehose and then have it stored in a bucket or cluster in the same region as the Firehose.

Comment: That's fine. I think the current idea is that I would have several AWS Lambda functions that output to a specific Firehose stream.Would that also be not supported? Also I cannot create a firehose stream in the same region as the S3 bucket and redshift cluster in Account A.

Comment: You will need a Firehose in the same region as the place you wish to output the data (S3 and Redshift). Then you can send data to that stream from a Lambda function in any region (and even from any application on the Internet).

Comment: So with the initial configuration I tried creating everything across both accounts in US East 1. However, when creating the Firehose stream I do not see the S3 bucket or cluster as the output destinations. Would you know if something is wrong with my configuration or if there are any steps I am perhaps missing? As a added note, the versions on my initial policies were different which I did correct to be the same across all accounts and policies.

Comment: The Kinesis Firehose, S3 bucket and Redshift cluster must all be in the same region in the same AWS Account. However, you can *send* data to the Firehose from other regions and other accounts (with the right security configuration).

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't convey that earlier. Right now, I am trying to create the Firehose stream in Account A in US East 1 (N. Virginia) and the S3 bucket and Redshift cluster are also in US East 1 (N. Virginia). However, on trying to create the stream right now it does not show me the ability to create with that bucket and cluster.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, I missed the same account bit. Thanks!