# Ambiguous Firehose DeliveryStreamName

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Firehose name must be unique per AWS account per region (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDeliveryStream.html)

Put record operation on firehose requires DeliveryStreamName (not arn)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html

One can write to firehose under any AWS account in any region (given they have the correct permissions) https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464145/1299412

What happens if I have access to several firehoses with the very same name (either they are under different AWS accounts or in different regions) and I perform put operation on firehose with that name? I could not find this behaviour specified anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS CLI and SDKs will fallback to your default region or you need to specify one explicitly when creating a client / putting records.

Here is a sample output from the CLI:

```
% aws firehose put-record --delivery-stream-name test --record '{"hello":"world"}'
You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".
```